Laravel: Store query results in variable, then be able to query again using that variable
I'm facing a challenge in (wrongfully) generating a query inside a foreach loop. The problem is that Logs is being queried each time the loop runs. The code currently looks like this:
$logs = Logs::query(); // This table has about 100,000 rows

foreach ($data as $indiv_data) {

   $checkIfDataMatches = $logs->where('employee_id', '=', $indiv_data->employee_id)->first();

   if ($checkIfDataMatches === null) {

     // Not found

   }   

   else {
   
     // Found

   }

}


The code above means repeatedly fetching a table of 100,000 rows multiple times.
Is there a way to just fetch Logs once, store the collection to variable $logs, then just fetch data from the foreach loop by querying $logs? If yes, any help on how to do it would be appreciated. Thanks!

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/index-get-result-by-column, https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#method-groupby

Thanks for the feedback CBroe. I understand that collect() can be used. My question is that how do I build a new query (where, orWhere, etc.) with that new collection?

You don't make any more queries, you simply pick the relevant record from the array, using the employee ID.

Oh, I get what you mean now. However, if you don't mind reading my comment in OMR's answer, the scenario is actually a little more complicated as the loop is being done as I import a CSV file via Laravel Excel.

If the record is found $checkIfDataMatches you have to do something with it or you want just to know if it's present ?

the scenario is actually a little more complicated - so show the actual code if you expect a solution

Maybe you could iterate over the CSV content twice, first time to only gather the IDs, and the second time you do the actual processing. If that is not an option, then the only thing left to optimize I can see here, is if the employee IDs can occur multiple times in the CSV? Then you could implement "caching" of already fetched records in an array, so that you at least don't have to perform the same queries multiple times.

Maraboc yes, additional code will follow if there's a match. CBroe thanks for the constructive feedback. Will try to work around your suggestion if there really is no other efficient way.

additional code will follow if there's a match this additional code will use $checkIfDataMatches or not?

you should first get all employee ids then set them in array to use whereIn method query for them:
$employeeIds = collect($indiv_data)->pluck('employee_id')->unique()->toArray();

// notice that if $indiv_data is already a collection then you do not need collect method.
$allLgos= Logs::query()->whereIn('employee_id', $employeeIds)
    ->get();

now you have all Logs for employees that exists in $indiv_data
notice that you can chunk results if they has big size ...

Thanks OMR. Here's the thing though, I'm actually using Laravel Excel to import a CSV file containing the employee data. So there's no way for me to get all the employee ids beforehand. The spreadsheet is being iterated row by row, and if there are no errors, the whole thing gets imported.

i think you should import all data from excel then query the logs

Thanks OMR. Will try to work around this suggestion as there seems to be no other way.
